# Magento: Observer + Router + Controller not working

Tags: adminhtml, controllers, router

I'm working on a MassAction plugin for Sales/Order using Observer. I cant get the controller route to work.

Here is my etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Compressfiles>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Test_Compressfiles>
    </modules>

    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <Test_Compressfiles_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Test_Compressfiles_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>compressfiles</method>
                    </Test_Compressfiles_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before>
        </events>             
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <compress>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_Compressfiles</module>
                    <frontName>compress</frontName>
                </args>
            </compress>
        </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

</config>
```

my folder structure:

```
- Compressfiles
-- Model / Observer.php
-- Controllers / Adminhtml / Sales/ OrderController.php
-- etc / config.xml
```

Here is my controller - this is where I dont understand how to get the controller URL:

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php';

class Test_CompressFiles_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController {


protected function _construct()
{
    Mage::log("COMPRESS");
    die('it works');

}

public function indexAction() {

    Mage::log("COMPRESS");

    echo "test2";

}

public function compressAction() {

    Mage::log("COMPRESS");

    echo "test2";

}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused why you want your own router, and you're extending an existing controller. If you're just wanting to alter the behavior of `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController` then you'll just want a rewrite router for that controller, like so:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <test_compressfiles before="Mage_Adminhtml">Test_Compressfiles_Adminhtml</test_compressfiles>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

And I also suggest changing `Test_CompressFiles_Sales_OrderController` to `Test_Compressfiles_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController` and moving it to `app\code\local\Test\Compressfiles\controllers\Adminhtml\Sales\OrderController.php`

If, on the other hand, you're looking to just create your own controller then I suggest starting with a tutorial like [this](http://www.greenacorn-websolutions.com/magento/building-a-magento-admin-module.php).

Comment: Thanks, I will try your solution today.

PS: I'm trying to make a Mass Action in Sales/Order section that will Compress files of the Orders.